# $.getJSON not working on Mac OS 10.8?

Tags: php, jquery, osx-mountain-lion

Here's my code, which was working fine a few months ago:

```
$.getJSON("php/loadSites.php", function(result){

            console.log("LOADING QUERY...");

            $.each(result.Sites, function(i,v){

                site_list_array.push('<li class="site" id='+v.Site.plant_code+'> <b> '+v.Site.plant_code + '</b> ' + v.Site.city +'</li>');  //build small array for the sidebar
            sites.push(v.Site); // build large array of all site data
        });

            $('#site_list').html(site_list_array.join('')); // dynamically update the webpage with the results of the query
        });
```

...and for some reason today, it just fails to execute? (It won't even display the 'loading query' line to the console log.) It doesn't throw any error messages...it simply seems to be ignoring everything inside the $.getJSON call.

The only thing that has changed was I updated the server to Mac OS 10.8. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Can you browse to php/loadSites.php? Does firebug say anything?

Comment: @jarchuleta, yes, the loadSites.php is there, and no, firebug, nor the console say anything. No errors at all..it's just as if the code within $.getJSON is completely ignored, while everything around it renders find.

Comment: You may note that you enter your callback only on success. Perhaps for some reasons, php/loadSites.php does not give json (displays a warning/error on output, or such?)

Answer (score 2):

Load your browser's development tools (CMD+OPT+I in Chrome and Safari, F12 for Firebug in Firefox if I recall) toggle the Net[work] tab and reload your page. Check if loadSites.php is being requested at all, and if it's returning an error.

If your PHP script is throwing an error your callback won't be called, which is probably what you're seeing.